# ReSharper add all fixtures to unit test sessions window?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2010, nunit, resharper

I'm on a large project, with hundreds of test fixtures.

Is there a way to add every fixture to a unit test session other than going through the code and adding each one individually?

BTW, I'm using VS2010 Ultimate and R# 5.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind, I found it.

1. Right click the project in solution explorer
2. Click 'Debug Unit Tests'
3. It adds them all to the test session for you

Comment: Is there a way to add them and not start them running?

Answer (score 4):

You can also manage the unit tests in a session via the [Unit Test Explorer](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/unit_testing.html) (`Resharper | Windows | Unit Tests` or `Ctrl+Alt U`)

You can then right mouse click on the root of the tree and Append Tests to an existing Test Session (`Ctrl+U, A`), or Create a new Test Session (`Ctrl+U, N`)